# Differentiate a video or image on file upload JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've searched whether it is possible for JavaScript to differentiate whether the file is a video or image. However there were just multiple sites showing how to accept those types on the input tag.

**However, what I need is how can JS determine the file type, then display the file URL in either an image or the video HTML tag.**

Currently when a user is to upload a file, I have used this as my file upload input:

```
<input accept="image/*,video/*" multiple="multiple"  onchange='openFile(event)' style="display: none" type="file" id="selectedFile" />
```

But instead of the user having to "select" whether it is a video or image, the browser can find the file type and assign to file source to the right source element.

My current code which uploads the file creates a `data:url` for the image or video that the user uploads and sends it through a socket which displays to others presently on the site as shown below:

```
var openFile = function(file) {
    var input = file.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        try {
            var file = reader.result;

            Toast.fire({
                title: 'Uploading your File...',
                text: " ",
                didOpen: () => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                },
            })

socket.emit('message', `

//
//
// However how can it differentiate which tag to use and use the uploaded data URL??
//
//

<video controls autoplay="1" alt="Video Uploaded" style="cursor: zoom-in; border-radius: 4px; width: 16rem" src="${file}">

<img alt="Image Uploaded" style="cursor: zoom-in; border-radius: 4px; width: 16rem" src="${file}">
`);
        }
        catch (err) {

        }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

***I'm not using a blob for the file as it will not show for other users when sent through the socket. I also would rather use on file input button as I'm trying to keep things as simple for the user as possible.**

TL;DR:

1. User clicks a "Upload file" button
2. User can upload either video or image files from the same input button
3. JS create a dataURL link and finds the file format
4. JS assigns which attribute tag ( or ) the file will display in
5. Sends through socket for others to see

Really appreciate if anyone can help! Thanks.

Comment: Test the file extension?

Comment: But only test whether it is a video or image? Then source the file to the right tag, <img> or <video>

Comment: mp4, avi, mkv etc --> video; jpg, jpeg, png etc --> image

Comment: Yes then when their format is found, how can the right tag be applied?

Comment: `video.src="filename.mp4"` or `image.src="filename.jpg"`

Comment: Sorry, I just need some better explanation, how can the type be identified first? then use video.src="..." or image.src="..."

Comment: To get the extension : `let ext = file.name.split(".").pop(); if (["jpg", "jpeg", "png"].includes(ext.toLowerCase())) { yourImageElement.src = file.name };` Same thing with `["mp4","avi","mov"]` for videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `reader.result` contains MIME type of the file, from it you can detect if it's image or video or something else:

```
var openFile = function(file) {
    var input = file.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        try {
            var file = reader.result;

            Toast.fire({
                title: 'Uploading your File...',
                text: " ",
                didOpen: () => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                },
            })
var match = reader.result.match(/^data:([^/]+)\/([^;]+);/) || [];
var type = match[1];
var format = match[2];
if (type == "video")
{
  socket.emit('message', `
<video controls autoplay="1" alt="Video Uploaded" style="cursor: zoom-in; border-radius: 4px; width: 16rem" src="${file}">
`);
}
else if (type == "image")
{
  socket.emit('message', `
<img alt="Image Uploaded" style="cursor: zoom-in; border-radius: 4px; width: 16rem" src="${file}">
`);
}
        }
        catch (err) {

        }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

With it, you also can fine tune it by filtering based on `format` (it's not exactly a file extension, but rather a type of image/video, for example `.mov` = `quicktime`).